# How to restrict a multiline textbox to accept only one Number?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

In model

```
    [Display(Name = "Message")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [RegularExpression(@"??????????")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
```

In view I am using

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

What regular expression I need to use so that the above Multiline Textbox will accept only string having one number only.

Example:-
**Validate input:-**

*Salary amount 20000,

Please increase amount 3000,

xyz 3000 yxed abc*

**Invalid Input:-**

*asas aswas 200 asa 300 asa 3300,

xyd rooo 4000 3*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?!(?:.*?\d+\b){2})[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

You can try this regex .See demo.It uses lookaehad to make sure string has exaclt one `number`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU4xK1/8

Comment: thanks. It work for me. i need bit modification in this. only string without number should also be a valid input . how to do that?